# (Additionally) implementing row archiving in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I do realize I am definitely not the first one to be dealing with this, but I have some context to it and I was not able to find a satisfying answer.

I have a table `T` used in `x` MySQL triggers (including ON DELETE), `y` PHP scripts and `2` views `VT` and `VT2` (the `V` prefix is a naming convention I have). Speaking about the application, one can expect new functional requirements to appear incrementally, so the structure of `T` is alive.

Now, in the application, I need (additionally) to implement archiving of rows from `T` (deleting them, but with a backup).

There are two solutions:

1) Add a boolean column `archived` and create a view, smth like `VCurrentT`, and replace all `x+y+z+2` occurrences of `T` with `VCurrentT`.

2) Create a backup table `T'` (for the same entity as `T`) and extende the ON DELETE trigger in `T`.

Now the pros and cons:

ad 1) I find it more elegant and correct, however there will be a notable portion of rewriting (possible source of errors). Also I doubt the correctness of the view naming (`VT` is derived from `VCurrentT`) - probably the `VT` and `VT2` views should be renamed - even more rewriting!

ad 2) It is easier to implement and it could possible be faster (no no-more-used archived rows in the table), but I don't find it as elegant. We would need to maintain two tables.

What do you find better?

Comment: There's no performance issue? It's not one of those cases when you get millions of tweets per day (just an example - I don't think twitter really uses mysql, but anyway-), and almost nobody's interested in 1-year-old tweets, and keeping them in the main/live table makes it a moster that's impossible to replicate/backup/etc...?

Comment: It will be like thousands of records per day. It could be 'deleted' (archived) for various reasons. I don't dare to guess how often the deletion will be done. At this stage the application won't even access the archived rows, to the users it will be presented as deletion. Now it's just a backup for an exceptional data restoration, so nobody should really care about the deleted data. However foreign keys should be kept (there are some _child_ data in another tables referenced from `T`).

Comment: Quite a dilemma :(  I'm voting for this question. In our case, size issues tilted the scales - we moved old data to a separate table so that it won't slow down replication. Indeed it cost us dearly in terms of giving up some FKs + limiting business operations on old data (well, we could have written each business code to work on either "T" or the View "T union T' "  but didn't have time for it).